# React ref with an id as attribute value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component and I'm attempting to reference DOM node. I am able to get the nodes and the children by the following:

```
export class AutoScrollTarget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.targetId = props.targetId;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.refs.target);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="target">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is there are going to be many components on the page and I would like the ref value to be the "this.targetId".

I have tried the following:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.targetId}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is there a simple and clean way to do this?

Comment: String refs have long been deprecated. Try using a callback for `ref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`ref` callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), which is a function that is called with the DOM node when the element is mounted and with `null` when the element is unmounted.

**Example**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div ref={ref => this.targetId = ref}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```